# Python: new line character in binaryarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, contains

I want to test if the binary array `b'volume\n1'` contains a new line character `"\n"`
How do I do that? I tested both `'\n' in word` and `"\n" in word` and both give the same error.

```
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

Comment: `b'\n' in b'volume\n1'`

Comment: Yes thank you, I just got that before you posted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b'\n' in b'volume\n1'
```

(provided by falsetru)

Comment: sorry i am very new here and have no idea how to do that!

Comment: The thread remains open "forever." If someone later has a better idea, they can post it, and you are free to accept their answer instead. Accepting an answer does two other things: 1) it allows people to skip your question, and 2) it rewards (with reputation points) the person whose answer you've chosen. (In this specific case, I have voluntarily forfeited any reputation points since this wasn't actually my idea, it was @falsetru's. That's what "community wiki" means under my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `bytearray` is an mutable array of small integers, and `string` is of type `string` so you cannot ask if it contains a string literal.

**Try** `ord('\n')`

In words, `ord` is a function that converts a `string` of size one to the ascii of that `char`, which is an integer.

For the very same reason you cannot do `word[1] = 'a'` or `word[1] = b'a'` but you can do `word[1] = ord('b')` or `word[1] = b'a'[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
    >>> a = b"volume\n1"
    >>> "\n" in a
    True
    >>> "\b" in a
    False
    >>> b"\n" in a
    True
    >>>
```

However, the code is right here.

Comment: It's a python2 -vs- python3 thing. You're testing with python2 and the OP has python3.